# A Pre/postposition that resembles Proximity, Multiplicity, and Miniature (or any of the three)

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I am looking for a preposition or postposition that shows one or all of the following characteristics

The order matters:

1. Proximity
2. Multiplicity
3. Miniature

The word I am looking is something like "let" that is added to book to make the word booklet (that resembles miniature). But "let" does not show multiplicity and especially proximity.

I was thinking of "Leaf", but I guess it only shows thinness and miniature. The most important feature I am looking for is proximity and closeness.

Pls let me know If further explanation required. Thanks

Comment: If what you're asking for are suggestions for prefixes or suffixes, you've got three of them in the words you've listed - you could compound them and get a 'minipromulti-' - a context or example would be useful.

Comment: +1 That reminds me of *-litter* (that cute gang of puppies). But seriously, it's a tall order, yours. Let us try. What's the main word, by the way?

Comment: *Epicloudlets* works logically, with *epi-* for proximity leading the way, multiplicity made easy with the concluding "-s," and your own "-let" for miniature. It registers as something having to do with "epic," though, which defeats the sense of "minuature." Thus it doesn't work in practical terms unless hyphenated: epi-cloudlets. Ugh. Good neologisms are tough!

Comment: Thanks Joan. Which one do you prefer personally Epicloudlets or cloudleaf?

Comment: I can't speak for Joan, but I definitely prefer *epicloudlets*. Are you specifically looking to modify *cloud*? (I didn't see that the main word was ever established.)

Comment: thanks John. I think epi is good prefix here. many thanks

Comment: "Epi-" makes me think of the EpiLady product that pulled leghair out of women's legs.

Comment: @Oldcat, hehe, nice joke

Answer (score 1):

It's not really an affix (if that's what you're looking for). But I would say that the word "swarm" comes close to what you're looking for.

A swarm is made up of many small actors, gathered around a central point. So if you're talking about, for example, photographs, you could call it a "photo swarm."

Or if that doesn't convey the type of proximity you're looking for--again, it's a little vague--you could add the word "personal." So you have a "personal photo swarm."